# How can I restart an iPhone 4S with a broken lock button and frozen springboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware, reboot

My springboard has frozen and the lock button is broken (two months out of warranty and it's not classed as a hardware failure).

How do I restart the phone given that I can't access any apps or settings?

Waiting for the battery to drain will take days, so that's not an option. Is there a way through iTunes to force a reboot or is there a program I can download to force a reboot?

Comment: Make a backup through iTunes, then restore to factory settings?

Comment: The most obvious answer is to let the phone's battery run out, which will force the device to turn off.

Answer (score 11):

If you're lucky, you have enabled fast-switching to Assistive touch. Try triple-clicking the Home-button. If there's an option called *Assistive Touch* popping up, click it and you'll find where you can put it to sleep or power off by holding the lock screen button.

If not, there isn't really any other option. You could try these tips I got at Apple Support Disscussion:

> You can squeeze (pinch) the Power Button top corner front glass to the back case while pushing the Power Button and the Power Button will usually function.

If you have jailbroken your iPhone and by chance enabled SSH, you could connect to it and reboot it from there, following [this guide](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/guide-how-to-reboot-respring-and-safe-mode-via-ssh.369899/).

Barring that, you could run a game or other CPU intensive application like mapping to accelerate the battery drain and get the device to power itself off.

Answer (score 11):

Go to settings general then accessibility. Turn bold text on and it will reboot your iPhone and fix a springboard crash. I was having the same problem and lucked out and found this!

Comment: This is amazing! A software enforced reboot option on iOS. Thank you for documenting this. Whether or not this "springboard" freezing means that you can't launch the settings app (or get Siri to open the app for you) still makes this a unique thing since iOS doesn't have a restart option anywhere else I know of.

Comment: But if the springboard is frozen, how do you get to the Settings app?

Answer (score 5):

Enable AssistiveTouch:  Tap Settings, General, Accessibility, AssistiveTouch (near the bottom) and tap AssistiveTouch to ON.

You will now notice a small dark square with a circle in the middle (you can move this square anywhere).  Tap the dark circle to open the AssistiveTouch menu, then tap Device and tap and *hold* the Lock Screen icon.  This will bring up the iPhone's Power-Off slider - no need for a power button any longer!

I saw this when I was trying to figure out how to turn my phone off and it works!

Answer (score 2):

If you push the lock button (even though it doesn't work) against a hard surface (I used a counter) and hold home button the phone will reset.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download and install [Reiboot](http://www.tenorshare.com/products/reiboot.html).
2. Connect your iPhone to your Mac.
3. Run Reiboot on your Mac.
4. It will detect your iPhone. Press *Enter recovery mode* button, and wait for it to take action.
5. Press *Exit recovery mode*, and it'll exit recovery mode, rebooting your iPhone. Your phone will come back on after the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to eat the battery is press the Home button until voice option is on and put the music on until it empties the battery.

When iPhone is plugged in when the battery has depleted, it will turn on automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the battery drains, and then plug into power adapter to turn it on. Otherwise, reset to factory settings from iTunes if you already had a backup previously.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck it in the freezer for awhile. Makes the battery on my die rather quickly.

Answer (score -1):

I read that if you let the battery die it will be forced to turn off and if you plug it in and let it charge it wont be frozen

Answer (score -2):

Remove the 2 screws next to the charging port and slide the back off. Carefully pry the battery clip out and your phone will shut off. Plug it back in and your phone will turn on again.  NOTE: you can damage your phone if this isn't done correctly. Be careful!

Answer (score -3):

My phone has the same problem. I looked it up, and it just said let it die out. So just let it die.

Answer (score -4):

You can open your iphone, remove your battery and just plug it on again and  then connect the usb charger cable and voila, done!

You can see the instructions to remove the battery and plugit in again here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYvjuWg06l4

Comment: This is an extreme measure; using a mallet for a fly. Removing the battery is far from trivial and doing any type of hardware adjustment is better (read: safer) with the power off. And in the case of the battery, its probably better just to let it drain completely, which will force the phone to power off.

Answer (score -5):

or gust press the home button and the power / lock button the same time until it reload.
its easy guys!

Comment: Pressing a broken lock button won't really work, now will it?